# BFGMINER error while loading shared libraries

Tags: linux, ubuntu, asic, bfgminer

I just installed BFGMINER on my Ubuntu 12.04LTS laptop and it won't let me set it up with my pool.

```
administrator@T41-Server:~$ sudo bfgminer -o api.bitcoin.cz:8332 -u wizardmorax.ibm_ubuntu -px -S all
bfgminer: error while loading shared libraries: libblkmaker_jansson-0.1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I followed a tutorial for installing BFGMINER
http://www.linuxconsultantsireland.com/content/bitcoin-mining-raspberry-pi-usb-asic-miner-block-erupter

Thanks,
Jackson

Comment: Why are you running it as root? That could be one problem.  Also you should be connecting to _stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333_ not the API.

Comment: You appear to be using a version compiled under a different system. If you'd compiled it on yours then the library should be present.

Answer (score 7):

Type "ldconfig" to update the links